# How to organize GWT project with multiple modules and shared server?

Tags: gwt, module

I have three GWT modules that will have some code in common - typically domain classes  - and also share the same server instance. My first thought was to organize it like this:

> app1/client/
>   app2/client/
>   app3/client/
>   server/
>   shared/

The modules would then have in their descriptors:

> `<source path = "client"/>`
>   `<source path = "../shared"/>`

But it seems like that the `../shared` path is not working.

Is this the way to go, or are there better ways?

Answer (score 4):

I found at least on solution that works: Have all the modules in the same package, like this:

> client/app1/App1.java
>   client/app2/App2.java
>   client/app3/App3.java
>   app1.gwt.xml
>   app2.gwt.xml
>   app3.gwt.xml
>   server/
>   shared/

I still kept subpackages app1, app2 and app3, but that's off course optional.
With this organization the module descriptors should say:

> `<source path = "client"/>`
>   `<source path = "shared"/>`